# Update DataSet, How?

Tags: c#

I have DataSet that I fill like this:

```
      dsView = new DataSet();
        adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Worki", Conn);
        adp.Fill(dsView, "Worki");
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables["Worki"].DefaultView;
```

If I change any cell in the Datagrid, How I can update the DataBase too ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think Paul Domag has a nice solution exactly for your problem called "[How to insert, update, delete using DataGrid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d402f6f4-52c6-48e3-88a6-4d6fbececf8a)".

Comment: I dont want to use sql query, I only want to change cell in the datagrid and that change will be in the Database too